# react-bootstrap change active tab programmatically

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I have a tab setup similar to [this code](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs-with-dropdown). I need to change the active tab programmatically.

I'm trying to do like it is documented on [bootstrap's official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) but it doesn't work.

Comment: We need a bit more than that. Can you include a snippet of your actual code (the relevant HTML and JavaScript would be a start) so we can try it ourselves. Even better, add it as a StackSnippet or create a JSFiddle or Bootply.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the native javascript `document.getElementById(tabId).click();`.